# Removing Rails/Spree image upload limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, spree

My client called today because they couldn't upload their images to their shopping site, and I have absolutely no idea where the upload file size limits are configured.

So here's my server configuration: Ubuntu 10.04LTS, Spree on Rails 2.3, Nginx.

Basically I want to remove the file-size upload limit.

Anyone know where I should go to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your Nginx config?

More specifically the [client_max_body_size](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) directive?

To make sure your Spree install is not rejecting the file, fire up `script/server` locally and try uploading a big file to it.

Answer (score 0):

Spree uses Paperclip (http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for it's image processing and management. You might also check there for a size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also checkout spree-user google group for Spree-related questions.  You might get a faster response there.

Answer (score 0):

So you really want your client to upload their 18 megapixel images from their DSLR directly to the site? Or, did you ask them how large the images are they want to upload? As others already said, there are several places where file size can be limited. In addition, the image files might be encoded, so the limit can be much lower than you'd expect.